# Why doesn't Powershell output error when using a variable or attribute that does not exist?

Tags: powershell

For example if I do:

```
PS> foreach ($i in $list)
{
    Write-Host $i
}
```

Produces no error, just a new command prompt.

```
PS>
```

Even when calling attributes on objects that don't exist, don't output any error:

```
PS>(Get-SPWeb "http://homesite").Sites
```

New command prompt

```
PS>
```

Yet it should be:

```
PS>(Get-SPWeb "http://homesite").Site
```

Correct results:

```
Url                                                     CompatibilityLevel  
---                                                     ------------------  
http://homesite                                         15
```

Comment: Use `Set-StrictMode -version 2` and you'll get your errors.

Comment: Answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905633/no-error-when-selecting-non-existing-property

Comment: @wOxxOm - I'd actually be inclined to `Set-StrictMode -Latest` and 'force' PS to whine about other sorts of things as well. But then, I like fascist programming languages; I'm less likely to end up with subtle logic bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's simply the way PowerShell was implemented, however there are many ways to check for keys on Objects.

#### Least Pedantic:

```
$s = Get-SPWeb "http://homesite"
if (!$s.Sites) {Write-Error "Invalid Key used!"}
```

#### Moderately Pedantic

```
$s = Get-SPWeb "http://homesite"
if ($a.sites -eq $null) {Write-Error "Invalid Key used!"}
```

#### Very Pedantic

```
$s = Get-SPWeb "http://homesite"
# gm is an alias for Get-Member
if (!($s | gm -MemberType Properties | % Name).contains("sites")) {Write-Error "Invalid Key used!"}
```